# Javascript split a string and remove leading 0

Tags: javascript, split

I am very new at jquery...how would I split a strings like this:

```
readybuilt-ANT-133.pdf
readybuilt-VIC-041.pdf
```

so I get just the numbers 133 and 41

this what I tried thus far

```
var str = this.home_pdf;
          var res = str.split("-");
          var lotNumber = res[2].split(".");
          lotNumber = lotNumber[0];
          console.log(lotNumber);
```

this works well, but how would I remove the leading 0s?

Comment: What's the `jQuery` about in this question? Re-tagged.

Comment: Looks like a regular expression might be more reasonable. `str.match(/([1-9]+\d*)\.pdf$/)`

Comment: `str.split(/\.|-0*/)[2]`

Comment: `+str.split('.').shift().split('-').pop()`

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Try [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)`( lotNumber, 10 )`. It will not care about leading zeroes when given an appropiate radix parameter.</strike>

P.S: obviously, regex is the way to go here.

A much better way is to use Bergi's method

```
var str = "readybuilt-VIC-041.pdf";
var lotNumber = str.split(/\.|-0*/)[2];
console.log( lotNumber );
```

Comment: parseInt('readybuilt-VIC-041.pdf'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10);

Answer (score 2):

Parse the variable as an integer:

```
lotNumber = lotNumber[0];
lotNumber = parseInt(lotNumber,10);
console.log(lotNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `this.home_pdf` contains the string, this should do the trick:

```
var str = this.home_pdf;
str=parseInt(str.replace(/\D/g,''));
if(str.match(/^0/g)){
    str=parseInt(str.replace(/0/,''));
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you pass a radix parameter to `parseInt` just to be safe

Comment: if you do a `parseInt`, you will no longer need to do a regex replace as the string representation of an int will not have leading zeros.

Comment: @SomeGuy: No. That's what we remove leading zeroes for :-)

Comment: in some rare cases it will cause problems! believe me I've faced with it!

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I wasn't about to post it, but I think it's better to be safe just in case something else in the input changes

Comment: @AminJafari: Haven't seen the issue so far. Could you share those rare cases for future reference?

Comment: for instance if your string starts with alphabets then "NAN" is the returned value, or if you do it like "1s2s" only "1" is returned, so you need the `replace` function to get the numbers out first and then parse it as an integer! @naveen @Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, using `match()`

```
'readybuilt-ANT-133.pdf'.match(/(?=[1-9])([0-9]+)/g);    // 133
'readybuilt-VIC-041.pdf'.match(/(?=[1-9])([0-9]+)/g);    // 41
```